# How to create Procfile for playframework app deploy in Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

i developed a small play framework web application and i am deploying it online on heroku then i went through steps of how to [deploy app in heroku](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionHeroku) ,i followed all the steps and i am having free account, i am getting error when i am running this command `heroku ps` in command line.

i wrote in **Procfile :**

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

**Error is** :

```
rahul@inext:~/EntWebPrj$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}`
web.1: crashed 2013/08/21 15:29:19 (~ 4m ago)
```

and it is also not running on [my app link](http://safe-castle-6943.herokuapp.com/) it is showing some application error.

anyone give some idea to fix this error?

Comment: You will need to use `heroku logs` to see what the startup error is.

Comment: You have to check the log, maybe a error in Global?